# TypeError: errorHandler is not a function

Tags: node.js

I'm trying out to handle errors more professionally in my ecommerce Web app. However, I keep getting this error repeatedly (TypeError: errorHandler is not a function), even after doing the npm install errorhandler. this is the app.js code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv/config');
const authJwt = require('./helpers/jwt');
const errorHandler = require('./helpers/error-handler');

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors())


//middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(authJwt());
app.use(errorHandler())
```

the error-handler.js file is as shown

```
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        return res.status(401).json({message: 'The user is not authorized'})
      }

      if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
        return res.status(401).json({message: err})
      }

      return res.status(500).json(err);

}
```

this is the error on my console

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\moodboard\app.js:19
app.use(errorHandler())
        ^

TypeError: errorHandler is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\moodboard\app.js:19:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Do you explicitly export `errorHandler` from `error-handler.js`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not exporting the function from the error handler file. When your app.js file tries to get the function from the required file, there is nothing for it to grab.

### Adding an export in ES6 and CommonJS:

#### ES6 Module:

```
export default function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
      return res.status(401).json({message: 'The user is not authorized'})
    }

    if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
      return res.status(401).json({message: err})
    }

    return res.status(500).json(err);
}
```

#### CommonJS:

```
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
      return res.status(401).json({message: 'The user is not authorized'})
    }

    if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
      return res.status(401).json({message: err})
    }
    
    return res.status(500).json(err);
}

module.exports = errorHandler
```

Comment: Zachary Johnson, executed your word, im now getting an error that says 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')' in the case of CommonJS

Comment: Well, finally  I got it. After exporting the function, I got rid of the function brackets in app.use(errorHandler()) to app.use(errorHandler).